# SparkR doesn't work while SPARK works

Tags: r, apache-spark, rstudio, sparkr

Following the question here:
[Unable to launch SparkR in RStudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31119150/unable-to-launch-sparkr-in-rstudio)

I encountered problem using SparkR. I used the following:

```
> Sys.setenv(SPARK_HOME='C:/Users/aw/Downloads/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/bin')
> .libPaths(c(file.path(Sys.getenv('SPARK_HOME'), 'R', 'lib'), .libPaths()))
> sc=sparkR.init(master="local")

Launching java with spark-submit command C:/Users/aw/Downloads/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/bin/bin/spark-submit.cmd   sparkr-shell C:\Users\aw\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp8CCseT\backend_port1cc4622cb87 
Error in sparkR.init(master = "local") : 
  JVM is not ready after 10 seconds
In addition: Warning message:
running command '"C:/Users/aw/Downloads/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/bin/bin/spark-submit.cmd"   sparkr-shell C:\Users\aw\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp8CCseT\backend_port1cc4622cb87' had status 127
```

We can see that I run the SPARK from the shell:
[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

I use Window 10 and R version 3.2.1 Patched (2015-07-16 r68681).

Comment: Thanks, I added the results to the question @DmitriChubarov Can you please look at the results?

Comment: `JVM is not ready after 10 seconds` can occur sometimes due to heap memory issues. try setting ` Sys.setenv(SPARK_MEM='512m')` and try initializing spark.

Comment: Did and got error: > sc=sparkR.init(master="local")
Launching java with spark-submit command C:/Users/aw/Downloads/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/bin/bin/spark-submit.cmd   sparkr-shell C:\Users\aw\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp8CCseT\backend_port1cc41e0d7eed 
Error in sparkR.init(master = "local") : 
  JVM is not ready after 10 seconds
In addition: Warning message:
running command '"C:/Users/aw/Downloads/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/bin/bin/spark-submit.cmd"   sparkr-shell C:\Users\aw\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp8CCseT\backend_port1cc41e0d7eed' had status 127

Comment: The PATH values are identical up to the prepended R-3.2.1 path in the first (error) case. So, something else is causing this `running command ... has status 127`.